# Migration Rejected

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions

[This question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18857/when-i-ask-ubuntu-the-interface-shows-number-of-answers-but-the-answers-are-not) was moved from main to meta (rightfully) but it was closed here as unclear, causing all commenting to be prohibited and it to become a rejected migration.

I understand why this would happen when moving from one main site to another but in this case it seems to be a bit harsh to lock the comments as the question seems to fit on meta but could do with an update.

My concern here is that the OP will realize they can't comment and just not know another way to respond to the requests for clarification, causing them to not be helped and us to look like we don't want to help.

Can a mod remove the migration rejected state and put the question just in to a normal closed state, allowing people to comment again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done now.  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)